# Trying to make a suggestion but channel id gives an error for the command

Tags: discord.py

I've got an issue but I am getting no errors and from the code I just wrote as shown below

```
@client.commands
async def hello():
    channel = int(797915093954199565)
    await channel.send('Hey what are you doing?')
```

I am trying to make a command where the user can talk to the bot, and it responds back with something, its just a starting command but I'm having trouble with these small things, the rest of the bot works but its just this issue i'm having please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming the rest of your bot and code works, your "hello" command isn't working because you have

```
@client.commands  #its client.command in this case, as it seems you are not using any cogs, and you must call the client with () these double parentheses 
async def hello():     #Here you have not passed ctx
    channel = int(793744805615632394)   #It seems what you would like to do here is send it to a specific channel, however, in the code below, I have set it so it just sends to the channel it was used in. The correct use is client.get_channel(793744805615632394)
    await channel.send('Hey what are you doing?')
```

Here is the command but fixed:

So assuming the rest of your bot and code works, your "hello" command isn't working because you have

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hey what are you doing?')
```

You should also refer to the py docs to learn more about it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/